# How to implement a security layer on a GATT server

Tags: authentication, security, bluetooth-lowenergy

**THE FACT**
I'm implementing a mobile app that reads and writes characteristics of a GATT server (BLE)

**THE DOUBT** 
All the reads and writes are "linear", meaning that once you're connected to the server you're free to read and write to its characteristics. I come from REST web development, where this would be a horrible thing, so I was trying to understand how can I secure my environment.

**THE PROBLEM** 
My GATT server is on a custom device that is always offline: this is what is stopping me, because I cannot perform a live validation against a server or something else (I use Firebase in this project to manage users in the app, but the GATT server cannot communicate with it since, again, it is offline).

**THE QUESTION** 
How can I implement a security layer on my offline server so that every read and write must be authenticated in some way?

Comment: Did you check out BLE pairing / bonding? With that you get some security.

Comment: There are 2 ways to do what you need: 1. Using Secure connection (pairing/bonding). 2. Use "custom" implementation: one of your characteristic is a "password" one. Once you send password to this characteristic others open and allow to read/write.